# Is my binary tree program reaching an overflow/recursive maximum?

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
  bool flag;
  char letter;
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
};
typedef Node* Nodeptr;

int stop = 0;

void splitString(string sequence, Nodeptr branch){
  //cout << sequence << " ";
  //cout << sequence.size() << endl;

  if(stop == 20) return;
  else stop++;

  if(sequence.size() == 1){
    branch->flag = true;
    branch->letter = sequence[0];
  }
  else{
    int half = sequence.size()/2;
    Node* left = new Node;
    Node* right = new Node;
    branch->flag = false;
    branch->left = left;
    branch->right = right;
    splitString(sequence.substr(0, half), left);
    splitString(sequence.substr(half), right);
  }
  return;
}

void print(Nodeptr root){
  if(root->flag)
    cout << root->letter;
  else{
    print(root->left);
    print(root->right);
  }
  return;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

  Nodeptr tree = new Node;

  splitString("Heaven on ", tree);
  print(tree);
  //the above two lines run fine

  Nodeptr tree2 = new Node;
  splitString("Heaven on E", tree2); //this code will run fine
  //print(tree2); //this code will give me an EXITED, SEGMENTATION FAULT error 
}
```

Considering that the two lines:

```
  splitString("Heaven on ", tree);
  print(tree);
```

run fine, but these do not:

```
  splitString("Heaven on E", tree2);
  //print(tree2); //this code will give me an EXITED, SEGMENTATION FAULT error
```

I come to think that I have reached the maximum recursion depth. I reviewed my code for the building and traversing the binary tree but I cannot find any problems there. What is the reason for the error? Thanks!

Comment: Seems unlikely that recursion is the problem -- can't quite decipher your logic, but you wouldn't appear to go more  than 11 deep.  I'm guessing you're somehow mucking up your node tree.

Comment: Hint:  Add some print statements.

Answer (score 0):

For two reason:

1. you are using a global, which is a very bad practice, and for example in this case you are not resetting it after the first `splitString`
2. you are not managing the case where the string has `0` as size, in the right way

This is a possible implementation of `splitString` which works (without globals):

```
void splitString(string sequence, Nodeptr branch){
    if(sequence.size() == 1){
        branch->flag = true;
        branch->letter = sequence[0];
    }
    else if (sequence.size() > 1){
        int half = sequence.size()/2;
        Node* left = new Node;
        Node* right = new Node;
        branch->flag = false;
        branch->left = left;
        branch->right = right;
        splitString(sequence.substr(0, half), left);
        splitString(sequence.substr(half), right);
    }
    else {
        branch->flag = true;
        branch->letter = '\0';
    }
}
```

There is surely a better way to do this, and i'll encourage you to change the data structor in order to makes it happen (for example don't use the `flag` to mark the leaves of the tree, just check if there is `left` is been set or is `nullptr`)